# How to update MySQL table by calculated form value?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update MySQL table recored by any calculated form values in php,  but it doesn't work. May you help me please thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Peoples in SO are like doctors bro ,we cant prescribe any medicine(fix) without seeing the patient(code).

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysqli with prepared statements, like so.

I hope this is enough for you, you gave me nothing to work with so...

```html
<?php

//Get the form value and ID of the database record to update
$value = $_POST['value']; // Value submitted by a form element (replace this with whatever you want to change)
$id = $_POST['id']; //ID, could be of the user etc. (this will be a primary key inside the database) (does not have to be submitted via POST, I assume you know this already)

//Establish a new mysql connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);

//Set up a query
$query = "UPDATE table SET column_one=? WHERE id=?";

//Prepare the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//Bind the parameters
// 'si' = in the order of submitted valurs (column_one=? and id=?) (column_one is s and id is i, s is for string, i is for integer) (this defines what types of variables we are sending)
$stmt->bind_param('si', $value, $id);

//Execute the query
if($stmt->execute()){
    
    //Get the amount of affected rows
    $affected = $stmt->affected_rows(); //Should only be 1, but if your ID or whatever you're using to define which parts of the DB to update is not unique, then it can go higher ofc.
    
    //Show success
    echo "Database updated, $affected rows affected";
}else{
    
    //Show error
    echo "Error, say that this is shown, on stack overflow, as there's obviously something wrong.";
}

//Close the stmt/mysqli stuff
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: plus one for making a clean explanation .